# Set a multiple field value on a form

Tags: 8, forms

I use this field definition in the entity "message" class.

```
$fields['fichier'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
  ->setLabel(t('Fichier attaché'))
  ->setSetting('file_directory', 'messagerie/fichier') // dossier d'upload
  ->setSetting('max_filesize', '10MB') // taille max du fichier
  ->setSetting('file_extensions', 'pdf doc txt xls zip rar mp3 mp4 csv jpeg jpg ppt') // extensions autorisées, à séparer par un espace
  ->setSetting('description_field', FALSE) // si on veut activer un champ « description »
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'file_generic',
    'weight' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

In the associated form I need to set this field a multiple field (I can't find a way to set cardinality in the definition field).
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BaseFieldDefinition::setCardinality()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/class/BaseFieldDefinition/8.7.x) for that, e.g.:

```
$fields['fichier'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
  ->setLabel(t('Fichier attaché'))
  ->setSetting('file_directory', 'messagerie/fichier') // dossier d'upload
  ->setSetting('max_filesize', '10MB') // taille max du fichier
  ->setSetting('file_extensions', 'pdf doc txt xls zip rar mp3 mp4 csv jpeg jpg ppt') // extensions autorisées, à séparer par un espace
  ->setSetting('description_field', FALSE) // si on veut activer un champ « description »
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'file_generic',
    'weight' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the cardinality to unlimited:

```
  ->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
```